# Confusion about continuity of derivative function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

So, I have the function $f(x)=|\sin(x)| +|\cos(x)|$ and I have to check differentiability of $f$ at the point $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Now $$f(x)= \sin(x) + \cos(x), \ \text{as } x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$ **and** $$f(x)= \sin(x) - \cos(x), \ \text{as } x \in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$$

So, left hand derivative:
 $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x) + \cos(x)), \ \text{as } x=\frac{\pi}{2} = -1$.

And the right hand derivative: $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x) - \cos(x)), \ \text{as } x=\frac{\pi}{2} = +1$.
As lhd $\neq$ rhd, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Is there anything wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: No, your argument is correct.

Comment: Your reasoning allows you to assure that the derivative of $f$ is not continuous at $\pi/2$, but tells nothing about its derivability at that particular point!

Comment: Then you guys are contradicting yourselves!

Comment: @user587126 Yes, we do! If you can compute the limit in Dr. Graubner's answer, proceed that way to determine whether $f$ is differentiable. Are you familiar with Taylor polynomials?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I want to know if my method of finding differentiability of the said function at $\pi/2$ is correct or not.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But i can't apply the same method to the function $g(x)=x^2sin(1/x)$ when $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Discontinuity of the derivative function does not apply non-differentiability,right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so if the derivative function is defined at a certain point then discontinuity of the derivative function at that point does  imply non-differentiability(like the functipn $f$).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir,I just want to know,if I am given a function like $f$,should i solve it by finding the limits as David did here or I just calculate both side derivatives(by diffetentiating the given function) and plug in the value of the given point? Second one seems easier to me but i don't know when the method is valid .

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos please explain if the second method is wrong in the above comment of mine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different questions here:

- 1: Is $f'$ defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$? (What you claim to have concluded)
- 2: Is $f'$ continuous at $\frac{\pi}{2}$? (What you ask on the title)

Obviously, 2 cannot be true without 1. Your reasoning proves that 2 is indeed false, but says nothing about 1 ($f'$ could still be defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$, despite not being continuous)

By definition, $f'(x)$ exists if, and only if, the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
exists and has a finite value. In our case, the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)|+|cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)|-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|cos(h)|+|sin(h)|-1}{h} $$

Can you solve this now simpler limit?

Comment: A function is differentiable at a point iff the right hand and left hand derivatives at that point are equal. OP's answer to 1) is correct and you are only  making things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That result is true, but it may be harder to prove than getting the limit

Comment: The result I stated does not even require a proof. It is immediarte from the definition of derivative.

Comment: Oh, sure! I thought you were refering to left and right limits of the derivative function. Anyway, how would you calculate the left and right hand derivatives without the limits? It is true that you can get rid of the absolute values, but still...

Comment: Since $f(x)=\sin\, x+\cos \, x$ for $0<x <\pi /2$ the left hand derivative if $f$ at $\pi /2$ is same as the actual derivative of $\sin\, x+\cos \, x$ at that point. This again is immediate from definitions.

Comment: Hmmm.. OK. That may be a simpler way (provided that a definition for left/right-hand derivative is known) Why don't you post it as an answer?